# Why this little program output True? Is GCC's overflow protection?

Tags: c, gcc, overflow

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){

    int x = 0x80000000;
    if((x-1)<1)
        printf("True");
    else
        printf("False");

}
```

this is from csapp practice 2.44, if this is compiler's operation, how to close it?

Comment: What do you mean by “close it”?

Comment: @EricPostpischil, close compiler's optimize operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming an `int` is 32 bit, the constant `0x80000000` is outside the range of an `int` and has type `unsigned int`.  When used to initialize an `int` it is converted in an implementation defined manner.  For gcc, that conversion results in `x` having the value -2<sup>31</sup> (whose representation happens to be `0x80000000`) which is the smallest value it can hold.

Then when you attempt to calcuate `x-1`, it causes signed integer overflow which is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  As an example of this, if I compile this code under gcc 4.8.5 with `-O0` or `-O1` I get "False" as output, and if I compile with `-O2` or `-O3` it outputs "True".

Comment: In gcc, '-o0', '-o1', 'o2' means different optimize level, and when i use '-o0', it return false, question solved, thanks.

Comment: @frozen Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.